# Not able to run simple program of iText library in android

Tags: android, itext

I want to run a simple iText program, here is my code:
http://pastebin.com/C6YMkYNk

It is working fine with Java but not in Android. I am using iText version 5.1.3. My code doesn't show any errors but also doesn't show a PDF file. Can anyone suggest what I need to do to solve my problem?

Comment: Please incorporate a minimal example of our source that duplicates the problem. Also, the question needs to be rewritten to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("a.pdf", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fOut);
```

You cant just start writing to the working directory. You have to store it on the sdcard

Comment: still not working..i have updated my code as here:http://pastebin.com/bynwweAQ     ectually when i run a code in java than pdf file is automatically created

Comment: What if you only use the openFileOutput and remove PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream("a.pdf"));

Comment: i tried this but & it deoesn' show any error but pdf is also not created

Comment: How do you know it's not created? (remember this will be saving it onto the device) Also make sure you're closing your output streams.

Comment: ectually it doesen't shows me any pdf file so...and ya here is my code  http://pastebin.com/ryAcEpWb

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that version of the library is optimized for Android dev as it contains several libraries that do not work for Android....such as the AWT libraries.

You need to contact their sales department to find out how to get your hands on the Android library of iText